# CSS, Display : block

Tags: css, block

There is a menu i have implemented lately, This is the link to the menu tutorial: http://pepsized.com/css-only-lavalamp-like-fancy-menu-effect/, My question take place at:

```
.nav a {
    display: block; // This line here
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em 0 2em;
    width: 25%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #393939;
    transition: .7s; }
    .nav a:hover {
      color: #c6342e; }
```

As you can check on this page: http://pepsized.com/demo/?id=1043 (The reason i want you to check on this page is so you can see effect take place for all 3 examples), So if you remove the `display : block` nothing is changed, All work the same way it worked with `display : blcok`, So i assume the `display : block`, Is mabye for older browsers, different browsers, But i can't point the reason, So if anyone know why the `display : block`, I will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float: left` or `float: right` forces `display` to have a computed value of `block`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

That is why removing `display: block` makes no difference. You can safely remove it if you want to.

The only possible reason to leave it there is to show your *intent* to anyone reading your CSS: that you *want* the element to be shown as a block-level element.

It was probably included in the first place because the author of that CSS was unaware that `float` forces `display: block`.

Comment: Thank you thirtydot, Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Display: block tells the browser that you want a certain element displayed in a "block": it is the only element on that "line" of the browser (so you can't fit multiple elements next to each other). You can also have "inline", which is the opposite. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I know what is block element and inline element what i asked was why when i remove the display block there is no change.

Answer (score 1):

SOURCE w3c

> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other,
>   vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical
>   distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin'
>   properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block boxes in a block
>   formatting context collapse.
>
> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a
>   box's content area may shrink due to the floats).

**AND ANSWER OF YOUR QUESTION**

**`position:relative` or `float:left/right;`** makes an element to behave like an block element..`display:block`; wont have any effect if you are using `position:relative;` or `float:left/right;`

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer, Can you explain the same this for the menu code...

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find all the values of the display property and its behaviour: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp